# The type 'local:EmailValidationBehavior was not found?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, behavior

Xamarin forms newbie here, trying to validate some user data. I've been following a guide online about setting up and verifying user information. Even after scrutinizing both my project and the sample code provided, I cannot seem to understand what assembly reference Im missing.

Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:PluralBuddy" 
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="PluralBuddy.Views.RegisterPage" NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Register your system" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Header" />
            <Entry Placeholder="System name" x:Name="EntryUserName" PlaceholderColor="SlateBlue" />
            <Entry Placeholder="Date of Birth" x:Name="DOB" PlaceholderColor="SlateBlue" />
            <Entry Placeholder="# of members" x:Name="NumUsers" PlaceholderColor="SlateBlue" />
            <Entry Placeholder ="Pronouns" x:Name="Pronouns"  PlaceholderColor="SlateBlue" />

            <Entry Placeholder="Email" x:Name="EntryEmail" ReturnType="Next" PlaceholderColor="SlateBlue">
                <Entry.Behaviors>
                    <local:EmailValidationBehavior />
                </Entry.Behaviors>
            </Entry>
            <Entry Placeholder="Password" x:Name="EntryUserPassword" PlaceholderColor="SlateBlue" />
            <Button Text="Register" Clicked="Registration_Action" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

[image]

[image]

Guide(s) im following:

https://dzone.com/articles/register-and-login-using-sqlite-in-xamarinforms

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/input-validation-in-xamarin-forms-behaviors/

Comment: what namespace is EmailValidationBehavior in?  (hint - look at the actual *.cs file, not the folder structure).

Comment: PluralBuddy.Behaviors is the namespace its located in. 

my local declaration is:

`xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:PluralBuddy.Behaviors"`

Comment: And now my code works???? Honestly must have been something really obscure or a really dumb typo :facepalm:

Comment: Steps I took: Changed namespace to be more explicit, cleaned and rebuilt solution, retyped code

Comment: you were telling it to look it the wrong namespace - once you corrected that it started working

Comment: Thank you very much for your help sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my situation I needed to better define / use namespace. I then cleaned and rebuilt my solutions and retyped the code in question.

Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338/jason

Comment: Hi , if have solved this , remember to mark answer when you have time .